# how to add custom column to CSV during generation in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, export

I am currently exporting a CSV file from my rails app and it is working fine but i would like to add a bit more data to the csv.

Currently i'm using:

```
 CSV.generate do |csv|
  csv << column_names
  all.each do |item|
    csv << item.attributes.values_at(*column_names)
  end
end
```

To generate a csv with all of the data from the target model but would like to add an additional column, manufacturer_name which will be taken from a parent model.. Something like:

```
 CSV.generate do |csv|
  csv << column_names,
  csv << "manufacturer_name"
  all.each do |item|
    csv << item.attributes.values_at(*column_names),
    csv << Manufacturer.find(item.manufacturer_id).first().name
  end
end
```

How would i write this correctly so that the "manufacturer_name" get set to a new column header and the manufacturer name of each item is pulled in and put in the correct column?

Comment: If the proposed answer solves your problem, please accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
CSV.generate do |csv|
  names = column_names << 'manufacturer_name'
  csv << names
  all.each do |item|
    row = item.attributes.values_at(*column_names)
    row << Manufacturer.find(item.manufacturer_id).first.name
    csv << row
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you explain why the field underneath Manufacturer would be blank, but then the space next to it has the text in? Here's my example with "map_title" http://cl.ly/image/1T170P0C2Y1X

Comment: @ItsJoeTurner, your question is beyond the scope of this one. I recommend researching the CSV library itself (http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) or asking your question separately from this question.

Comment: I agree with @ItsJoeTurner. I followed the example and the new header shows up next to the others but the actual rows have a blank space in between the original values and the new additional value. I'd say this answer isn't answered completely/correctly.

Comment: If anyone else is getting blanks because of the new column I followed this approach to get rid of them: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58598657/899904